# Typescript: How to pass array element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my project, I am trying to insert multiple values ​​at the same time through a text field. Added items and setItems for that. But now there is an error "
TS2345: Argument of type '(i: string) => any[]' cannot be assigned to parameter of type 'string[]'". I'm a beginner in react typescript, so any corrections when passing items? Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem.

email.tsx

```
const Email = (props: Props) => {
  const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
...
...
 <EmailChip
            placeholder="Enter Email Addresses"
            LabelName="Enter Email Addresses"
            className="textfield"
            tooltip="true"
            upload
            items={items}
            setItem={setItem}
          />
```

emailpage.tsx

```
type Props = {
  ...
  items?: string | any;
  setItem: (items: string[]) => void;
  ...
  const handlePaste = (evt: any) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
    const emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\\.-]+@[\w\d\\.-]+\.[\w\d\\.-]+/g);

    if (emails) {
      const toBeAdded = emails.filter((email: any) => !isInList(email));

      

      setItem((i: string) => [...i, ...toBeAdded]);
      console.log("items after", items);
    }
  };
  ...

};
```

error

[image]

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: Why does your your type declares `setItem` two times?

Comment: question edited and added the error screen too..

Comment: You are trying to pass a new function to `setItem` but `setItem` allows only array of string as an argument

Comment: Can you suggest how to rearrange that line?

Comment: Is `items?: string | any;` intentional and at all related to `setItems`? One is an array and the other is not. It's really hard to read your code samples with all the "...", braces don't match, etc. Can you clean them up to be more readable and reproducible if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to declare `setItem` as:

```
setItem: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>
```

And use it like this:

```
setItem((i: string[]) => [...i, ...toBeAdded])
```